# Why should the error vector be orthogonal to all of the column space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

Suppose we've a matrix $A$ and it's column space is $C(A)$. We have a vector $b$ that isn't in $C(A)$. We define error vector as $e=b-p$ where $p$ is a vector in $C(A)$.

It's said that the vector $p$ that leads to a minimum norm of $||e||$ has to be orthogonal to to all the subspace $C(A)$.

How do we justify that? Can anyone please help me with a proof for this. I'd be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be proved using calculus. Let $c_1, ..., c_d \in C(A)$ be a basis of $C(A)$. If $p = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^d \bar \lambda_i c_i$, then $\bar \lambda := (\bar \lambda_1, ..., \bar \lambda_d)^\top \in \mathbb{R}^d$ minimizes the functional $F: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
F(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_d) := \frac{1}{2}\left \lVert b - \sum_{i = 1}^d \lambda_i c_i \right \rVert^2.
$$
Therefore $\bar \lambda$ fulfils the first-order-optimality condition for every $k \in \lbrace 1, ..., d \rbrace$:
$$
0 = \partial_{\lambda_k} F(\bar \lambda) = \left( \underbrace{b - \sum_{i = 1}^d \bar \lambda_i c_i}_{=e} \right)^\top c_k
$$
So the error is perpendicular to every basis vector, meaning that it is perpendicular to $C(A)$.

Comment: Thank you but it's above me head at this moment. It's advanced

Comment: Which part is it that you have not learned yet?

Comment: The scary delta, the functional.

Comment: Do you know partial derivatives? The functional $F$ comes from the fact that if and only if, $p$ minimizes $\lVert b - p \rVert$, then it minimizes $\frac{1}{2}\lVert b-p \rVert^2$. I just wrote $p$ as a linear combination of basis vectors.

Comment: Thank you, I'm studying it.

Comment: If you don't mind can you elaborate on $0 = \partial_{\lambda_k} F(\bar \lambda) = \left( \underbrace{b - \sum_{i = 1}^d \bar \lambda_i c_i}_{=e} \right)^\top c_k$

Comment: Yes, a little later. What exactly do you want to know?